# Monitoring Kafka Spout

Tags: performance, apache-storm, apache-kafka

I am trying to monitor the performance of Kafka spout for my project. I have used the KafkaSpout that is included in apache-storm-0.9.2-incubating release.

Is it possible to monitor the throughput of kafka spout using the kafka offset monitoring tool? Is there another, better way to monitor the spout?

Thanks,
Palak Shah

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitoring Kafka Spout with KafkaOffsetMonitoring tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257608/monitoring-kafka-spout-with-kafkaoffsetmonitoring-tool)

Answer (score 1):

The latest Yahoo Kafka Manager has added metrics information and you see TPS, bytes in/out etc.

https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager

Answer (score 0):

We could not find any tool that provides the offset for all the consumers including the kafka-spout consumer. So, we ended up building one ourselves. You can get the tool from here:

https://github.com/Symantec/kafka-monitoring-tool

It might be of use to you.